# How to know the platform through InDesign javascript?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I want to find the platform (Windows/Mac) of the running indesign using javascript,

eg:  `alert(app.name)`;

will result `"Adobe InDesign"`

like the same way, is there any way to find the platform ?

please anyone suggest a solution for this

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$.os`, you can get os and version information.

```
alert($.os);
// => Macintosh OS 10.8.5
```

thank you